# Excel: How can I search a string for a number greater than something?

Tags: excel, search, formula

I'm in need of categorizing some items from our system where it's currently not available. They are TVs and have a description such as:

Sony 55in Pro Display w/ LED

One of the categorizations I want is for any TV over 32 inches. Is there anyway to do a search in the string for >32&"in" or >32&" in" or >32&"in." etc.

I'll be working with user-entered data so would need to do a few different checks..

Comment: give it a try and post back with your code to get help.   Since you state that it is user entered in data then I would also suggest maybe putting in some validation checks as there are probably a hundred different ways someone can enter in the information.  With Validation you can ensure the data is entered in a specific format. such as Make Model ect....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the string Sony 55in Pro Display w/ LED is in A1, use

```
VALUE(MID(A1, SEARCH( "in", A1 ) -2,2))
```

it should give the number 55.  go from there.

Note that this doesn't account for 3 digit numbers.  if you are sure no screens will be 1 digit (eg 9 inches) then just use

```
VALUE(MID(A1, SEARCH( "in", A1 ) -3,3))
```

Now obviously the product could have the letters "in", so then you'd maybe want to check if the resulting value is greater than zero etc.   So first, have the value end up in another column, and verify that each row is producing the right number, and get more specific if needed.

Comment: FIND is case-sensitive. SEARCH is a better option :)

Comment: this all makes me feel like I'm back in qbasic

Comment: + 1 LOL, I know what you mean. :)